# Can we see optimization problem as functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, dynamic-programming

I have optimization that goes the followings:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\max_{x_1,\dots,x_k} &&f_1(x_1)+f_2(x_2)+\dots+f_k(x_k)\\
&\text{subject to} &&x_1 + \dots + x_k = M\\
&&& x_1,\dots,x_k > 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

All $f_i(x_i)$ are strictly concave and continuous real function on the feasible region. I just wonder if we can see this optimization problem as function on $M$. In other word, to see it as a continuous mapping $H$ that map a given constraint $M$ to the optimal value.

If so, could we property apply property such as derivative/gradient on this function $H$?

Comment: If there is no optimal value, then the relation's range is empty, so cannot be a function.

Comment: The pseudo-inverse is a linear function that can be defined as an optimization function.

Comment: @DavidPeterson all fi are strictly concave and the domain is a convex set. This is convex-optimization problem and therefore admit unique otpimal solution/value.

Comment: @NicNic8 I am not sure how that related to the question I post. Could you elaborate on that? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is something that Lagrange multipliers do for us. There's a good discussion of this in [Boyd and Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) (free online). See section 5.6 ("Perturbation and sensitivity analysis.") "When strong duality obtains, the optimal dual variables give very useful information about the sensitivity of the optimal value with respect to perturbations of the
constraints." See eq. 5.58 in particular.

Comment: A relevant line from Boyd and Vandenberghe (p. 253, in the "shadow price interpretation" paragraph): "In other words, $\lambda_i$
tells us approximately how much more profit the firm could
make, for a small increase in availability of resource $i$." This is a classic reason that a business or economist might want to know the Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @littleO Thanks! that is very closed to what I wanted. If I understand correctly, the sensitivity analysis only provide a bound on how the optimal value changes as the contstraint change. I just wonder if there is a more rigorous and precise to quantify this change? like a derivative of function?

Comment: In certain cases, yes, the solution map of an optimization problem can be viewed as a function, mapping parameters (such as your $M$) to a solution. In some cases, it's also possible to compute the derivative of this function. As an example, see the paper [Differentiating through a Cone Program](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.09043.pdf) or Dontchev and Rockafellar's book [Solution Maps and Implicit Functions](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr234-Implicit2.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic programming often applies to problems with similar structure to this.  Let $g(k,M)$ denote the maximum value and note the recursion:
$$g(k,M) = \max_{0<y<M} \{f_k(y) + g(k-1,M-y)\}$$

Comment: I don't quite see how this related to the question I ask. Could you elaborate on this? Thanks.